# MDB MAP FULL error when syncing

Tags: synchronization, error-log

Ran into the following when syncing:

```
2017-06-26 21:19:28.150 [P2P1]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3383 Error adding block with hash:  to blockchain, what = Error adding spent key image to db transaction: MDB_MAP_FULL: Environment mapsize limit reached
2017-06-26 21:19:28.150 [P2P1]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-06-26 21:19:38.034 [P2P1]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-06-26 21:19:56.416 [P2P1]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-06-26 21:20:01.815 [P2P1]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-06-26 21:20:40.659 [P2P1]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
^C

^C
```

Anyone else encounter this?

Comment: You could try adding "--block-sync-size 20" to the monerod command line.

Answer (score 2):

Your errors indicate that your blockchain is most likely corrupted. To resolve this issue you need to resync from scratch. This is done by deleting `data.mdb` from `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` (Windows) or `$HOME/.bitmonero/lmdb` (Linux and Mac OS X), which will trigger the resync.

To avoid corruptions make sure to always gracefully exit `monerod`.

Comment: No, not necessarily corruption. Just a dramatic change in blocksize relative to recent history in the blockchain. Typically a stop/restart will get the DB resized large enough to progress further. Also should never happen any more, since PR#2457 was merged.